# Having issue with session in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My requirement is to save the data/value into session which i am passing it to controller via url.

ex: www.pulseofpublic.com/mobile/user_profile/user_forms/1 ( 1 is the user id)

```css
class user_login extends CI_Controller {

public function user_forms($user_id) {
     $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$user_id);
  $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
}
}
```

After running this code and open the session table in database value for user_id is "images" instead of 1.
If i write "echo "xyz";" before setting data into session using set_userdata. It is user_id=1.

```css
class user_login extends CI_Controller {
public function user_forms($user_id) {
echo "xyz";
     $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$user_id);
  $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
}
}
```

Why is this happening, Can some please help. I tried lot.

Please note :: session table is created in database and session library also loaded.

what is happening with out echo...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 1 thing that before making 'user_id' a session element, just clear it or remove it from session as 
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');

May be 'user_id' is already in session array as set by you.
Also just print all session data as 
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, As you suggested unset the userdata. but it did not work out. facing same issue